# How can I help Vapor successfully SSL-handshake my PostgreSQL server?

Tags: swift, postgresql, ssl, vapor, vapor-fluent

I'm using Vapor on a Ubuntu server to connect to my DigitalOcean-managed PostgreSQL database.

From the command-line, running the following works fine:

```
psql postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname?sslmode=require
```

But running the equivalent with the following code gives me:

```
Fatal error: Error raised at top level: NIOOpenSSL.NIOOpenSSLError.handshakeFailed(NIOOpenSSL.OpenSSLError.sslError([Error: 337047686 error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed])): file /home/buildnode/jenkins/workspace/oss-swift-5.1-package-linux-ubuntu-18_04/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 200
```

Here is the code:

```swift
    let postgres = PostgreSQLDatabase(config: PostgreSQLDatabaseConfig(
        hostname: Environment.get("POSTGRESQL_HOSTNAME")!,
        port: Int(Environment.get("POSTGRESQL_PORT")!)!,
        username: Environment.get("POSTGRESQL_USERNAME")!,
        database: Environment.get("POSTGRESQL_DATABASE")!,
        password: Environment.get("POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD")!,
        transport: .standardTLS
    ))
```

Switching the transport argument to `.unverifiedTLS` works.

I need help to let Vapor work out the SSL connection fine, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: It seems like your client can't verify the certificate of your ubuntu server either because it does not have the required trust anchor to verify the chain of trust or because you are using a self-signed certificate in your ubuntu server. Can you verify which is the case?

Comment: I am Having the same issue too. I am using a managed DB  from Digital Ocean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently got this working with Vapor 4 and MySQL on Digital Ocean, I suspect the same will work for PostgreSQL. The main bit was configuring Vapor to trust Digital Ocean's certificate.

1. Download the CA certificate from the managed database dashboard on Digital Ocean *(the connection details section)*.
2. Configure the database `tlsConfigurataion` to trust that certificate. Here's an example of what that could look like:

```swift
import NIOSSL

public func configure(_ app: Application) throws {
    app.databases.use(.postgres(
        hostname: Environment.get("DATABASE_HOST") ?? "localhost",
        port: Environment.get("DATABASE_PORT").flatMap(Int.init(_:)) ?? PostgresConfiguration.ianaPortNumber,
        username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "vapor_username",
        password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "vapor_password",
        database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "vapor_database",
        tlsConfiguration: try makeTlsConfiguration()
    ), as: .psql)
  // ...
}

private func makeTlsConfiguration() throws -> TLSConfiguration {
    var tlsConfiguration = TLSConfiguration.makeClientConfiguration()
    if let certPath = Environment.get("DATABASE_SSL_CERT_PATH") {
        tlsConfiguration.trustRoots = NIOSSLTrustRoots.certificates(
            try NIOSSLCertificate.fromPEMFile(certPath)
        )
    }
    return tlsConfiguration
}
```

In this example, I use the `DATABASE_SSL_CERT_PATH` environment variable to set the path of the downloaded `ca-certificate.crt` file.